# blockquote in NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

When i tried to convert html to attributed string, which contains "blockquote". It ignores the "blockquote" and return the string without it.

Is "blockquote" supported in iOS?

The code is below:

```
let data = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
             .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
        documentAttributes: nil
      )
```

The input string is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The blockquote element</h1>

<p>Here is a quote from WWF's website:</p>

<blockquote cite="http://www.worldwildlife.org/who/index.html">
For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally.
</blockquote>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some parts of your code seems missing, where do you use your input string? And what does `let data = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)` do?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Label displays the blockquote.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let html = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <blockquote>
            Test block quote.
        </blockquote>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

        let data = Data(html.utf8)

        if let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            label.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there is no any <html> tags but only <blockquote> in string i.e

`this is test for blockquite
<blockquote>
            Test block quote.
        </blockquote>
`